# Rocket port override from environment variable not working in Windows

Tags: windows, rust, port, rust-rocket

I'm trying to run a rocket-rs application while overriding the port configuration using environment variables as described in the [documentation](https://rocket.rs/guide/configuration/#environment-variables).

I've set the variable `ROCKET_PORT`:

```
setx ROCKET_PORT 4444
```

I've checked it was set with an `echo`. When I run the application (with either `cargo run` or `./application.exe`) it still uses port 8000:

```
  Configured for development.
    => address: localhost
    => port: 8000
    => log: normal
    => workers: 16
    => secret key: generated
    => limits: forms = 32KiB
    => tls: disabled
  Mounting '/':
    => GET /mine
    => POST /transactions/new application/json
    => GET /chain
    => GET /nodes/resolve
    => POST /nodes/register application/json
  Rocket has launched from http://localhost:8000
```

I know the port can be configured in `Rocket.toml`, but the idea is to be able to run in a different port for each console session by setting the environment variable.

Why would this not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the variable like this did the trick:

```
$Env:ROCKET_PORT=4444
```